# Удаление запятой в строке

Tags: массивы, java, android

Помогите решить проблему.
У меня TextView элементу присваивается строка "A,B,C,", как сделать так что бы после последнего элемента запятая не ставилась?

Вот код:

```
Cursor getMarker=db.getMarker(getDayId);
startManagingCursor(getMarker);

StringBuilder markersList= new StringBuilder();
getMarker.moveToFirst();
while(!getMarker.isAfterLast()) {
String myMarkers =   getMarker.getString(getMarker.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_MARKER_NAME));

getMarker.moveToNext();
markersList.append(myMarkers+", ");

}

holder.tvMarker.setText(""+markersList);
```

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант:

```
Cursor getMarker=db.getMarker(getDayId);
startManagingCursor(getMarker);

StringBuilder markersList= new StringBuilder();
getMarker.moveToFirst();
while(!getMarker.isAfterLast()) {
    String myMarkers = getMarker.getString(getMarker.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_MARKER_NAME));

    getMarker.moveToNext();
    if (markersList.length() > 0) {
        markersList.append(", ");
    }
    markersList.append(myMarkers);
}

holder.tvMarker.setText(""+markersList);
```

Comment: Если вас устраивает предложенное решение, вы можете отметить ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 3):

Можно по другому - так покрасивше будет, ну и заодно надо "почистить" цикл: убрав бессмысленные вызовы индекса и инициализации внутри вызова:

```
Cursor getMarker=db.getMarker(getDayId); 
startManagingCursor(getMarker); 
String myMarkers;
int markerNameIndex=getMarker.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_MARKER_NAME);

StringBuilder markersList= new StringBuilder(); 
while(getMarker.moveToNext()) { 
    myMarkers = getMarker.getString(markerNameIndex); 
    if (!getMarker().isLast()) { 
        markersList.append(", "); 
    } 
    markersList.append(myMarkers); 
} 
holder.tvMarker.setText(""+markersList);
```